# Fastest way to programmatically open prefpane?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

AppleScript was too slow, so I tried ScriptingBridge to open System Preferences.app and set the current pane, which is also too slow. Is there a faster way to do it? properly

Comment: Have you noticed the System Preferences.app is annoyingly slow to open no matter how it is invoked? Because I have noticed that.

Comment: Given your previous question and this one, you may want to have a look at this: http://0xced.blogspot.com/2008/02/upgrading-system-preference-pane.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Launch Services or NSWorkspace to open the prefpane bundle. That's the programmatic version of the open(1) command.

Comment: Indeed: `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:@"/Path/To/Foo.prefPane"];`

Comment: I'm not usually keen on this though as you have to figure out where your Third Party prefpane has been installed. Alas, using bundle identifiers with the appropriate NSWorkspace call doesn't seem to work.

Comment: There are only two places it could be, and you can use `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` to look in both of them.

Comment: Update from the year 2013: The modern replacement for `NSSearchPath…` is `-[NSFileManager URLsForDirectory:inDomains:]`, which returns an array of URLs rather than an array of strings that are paths.

Comment: @notedible, that isn't what I was suggesting. Arguably, it's better—it really should be its own answer.

Answer (score 13):

A more direct method than using the file system path is to use the appropriate resource URL for the preference pane with NSWorkspace as shown:

```
NSString *urlString = @"x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Accessibility";
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

where the `urlString` was taken from a list of some of the possible URL strings https://macosxautomation.com/system-prefs-links.html

Comment: Perfect! A much better method than the current accepted answer, especially because it allows you to open to a specific section in a pref pane. I was specifically looking to have it open to the Accessibility section of the Security pref pane, so your answer was especially relevant to me.

Comment: On second thought, this method isn't quite perfect, as it doesn't work in macOS 10.9. But it's not the end of the world to fallback on the other options and use this for 10.10 and later.

Comment: For 10.10+, this should be the accepted answer. Works perfectly.

Comment: I want to do this on a button press, but my app always takes focus back after System Preferences launches. Testing on MacOS 10.14.5

Answer (score 5):

No brainer:

```
system("open -a System\\ Preferences");
```

And to choose which Pane to open:

```
open /System/Library/PreferencePanes/Internet.prefPane
open /System/Library/PreferencePanes/DateAndTime.prefPane
...
```

Provided you found, with a little trial and error, the right file in `/System/Library/PreferencePanes/` first.

I'm sure there's a more **cocoa** way to do this last trick, still... this one works with every language.

> **Also:** you may want to check these paths
>
> ```
> /Library/PreferencePanes/
> ~/Library/PreferencePanes/
> ```
>
> ...as that's where third party apps install their `*.prefPane` files

Answer (score 0):

How exactly did you use the Scripting Bridge?

I tried with this code and I think it performs reasonably well:

```
SystemPreferencesApplication *SystemPreferences = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.systempreferences"];
@try {
    [SystemPreferences activate];
    SystemPreferences.currentPane = [SystemPreferences.panes objectWithID:@"com.apple.preference.security"];
} @catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [exception description]);
}
```

Here is another option just for fun which is Cocoa, but not documented at all (and only works with system preference panes). You may use it to compare performances, but don't use it in production code.

```
id bezelServicesTask = [NSConnection rootProxyForConnectionWithRegisteredName:@"com.apple.BezelServices" host:nil];
[bezelServicesTask performSelector:@selector(launchSystemPreferences:) withObject:@"Security.prefPane"];
```

Comment: I have the exact same Scripting Bridge code as you (well, minus the exception code) - I took mine from the Apple sample. The weird thing is that if I double-click on the prefpane file already inside the PreferencePanes folder, System Preferences opens and loads the pane instantly.

Comment: I tested using Scripting Bridge. But it turned out that it is EXTREMELY slow.